# cisco vpn client for mac

Tags: vpn, cisco, mac, cisco-vpn

What Mac application should I use to allow me to connect to Cisco VPN?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the [Cisco VPN Client](http://www.versiontracker.com/dyn/moreinfo/macosx/12696) for Mac.

Comment: Note: this does not work for current versions of OSX, use the built-in client instead.

Answer (score 4):

If you using snow leopard you have a cisco compatible VPN client built in. Go System Preferences -> Network -> Click the + sign to create a new interface. Choose VPN -> Cisco IPSec and the name it. Enter the details and then click Show VPN status in menu bar. This will make it easier to re-connect with the menu bar in the future.

Also if its a new cisco ASA if might already come with a SSL VPN which is java based and works great on any OS. You can reach it via https://your-vpn-hostname if your administrator has configured it.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try Equinux VPN Tracker, if you have the need to connect to other vendors of VPN concentrators.